# Returning std::vector<std::string>, but sometimes only

Tags: string, vector

I have a function that returns a std::vector of std::strings.
However if some check is not met at the beginning of the function, I bail out (for example there is no such user)

What would the correct semantics be for such a case, where I have nothing to return?

Comment: Is this an error condition or is it to be expected during normal operation of your program?

Comment: Maybe pass a `vector<string>` byref, fill it, and return a `bool`.

Comment: (In C, you would return a `char **` and it would be `NULL` on error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this in an error condition, then you should throw an exception. If an empty list is considered normal operation, then return an empty vector. The answer will depend heavily on your application.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it's easy because you have std::vector which can be empty. If you want to mark a result to be invalid you can use boost::optional.